# AD query in Powershell combine results in .CSV file

Tags: powershell, csv, active-directory

I'm trying to run a script from PowerShell to get users from 2 different OUs. I'm trying to export this into a .CSV file. However, the script I'm using isn't combining both Ous into one file, im only getting 1 OUs data.

the script im using:

```
$users = @()
$OU1 = "OU=Standard users,OU=US,DC=x1,DC=contoso,DC=com','OU=Standard users,OU=AS, DC=x1,DC=contoso,DC=com"
$OU2 = "OU=Standard users,OU=US,DC=x1,DC=contoso,DC=com','OU=Standard users,OU=AS, DC=x1,DC=contoso,DC=com"
$users  = Get-ADUser -Filter * -Searchbase $OU1 -Properties *|
Select-Object name, userPrincipalName, accountExpires, distinguishedName, physicalDeliveryOfficeName | export-csv -path "c:\users\$env:USERNAME\desktop\2-OU-List.csv"
$users += Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase $OU2 -Properties *|
Select-Object name, userPrincipalName, accountExpires, distinguishedName, physicalDeliveryOfficeName | export-csv -path "c:\users\$env:USERNAME\desktop\2-OU-List.csv"
```

now, when i take out the export option my script works in powershell but im trying to export it:

```
$users = @()
$OU1 = "OU=Standard users,OU=US,DC=x1,DC=contoso,DC=com','OU=Standard users,OU=AS, DC=x1,DC=contoso,DC=com"
$OU2 = "OU=Standard users,OU=US,DC=x1,DC=contoso,DC=com','OU=Standard users,OU=AS, DC=x1,DC=contoso,DC=com"
$users  = Get-ADUser -SearchBase $OU1
$users += Get-ADUser -SearchBase $OU2
```

Comment: If you looking for a side-by-side "combine" (based on e.g. the `Name`), you might use this [`Join-Object script`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Join)/[`Join-Object Module`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/JoinModule) (see also: [In Powershell, what's the best way to join two tables into one?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45483110/1701026)): `Get-ADUser -SearchBase $OU1 |Join (Get-ADUser -SearchBase $OU2) -on Name -Name OU1,OU2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Export-Csv` overwrites existing output file, unless parameter `-Append` is used. So you always end up with the output of the 2nd `Get-ADUser` query only.

Using parameter `-Append` you don't even need to store the `Get-ADUser` result into intermediate array `$users`, so the script will need less memory.

```
$OU1 = "OU=Standard users,OU=US,DC=x1,DC=contoso,DC=com','OU=Standard users,OU=AS, DC=x1,DC=contoso,DC=com"
$OU2 = "OU=Standard users,OU=US,DC=x1,DC=contoso,DC=com','OU=Standard users,OU=AS, DC=x1,DC=contoso,DC=com"

# Create a new, empty file (clear any existing file)
$file = New-Item "c:\users\$env:USERNAME\desktop\2-OU-List.csv" -Force

# Use parameter -Append to add to the existing CSV
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Searchbase $OU1 -Properties *|
    Select-Object name, userPrincipalName, accountExpires, distinguishedName, physicalDeliveryOfficeName | 
    export-csv -path $file.FullName -Append

# Use parameter -Append to add to the existing CSV
Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase $OU2 -Properties *|
    Select-Object name, userPrincipalName, accountExpires, distinguishedName, physicalDeliveryOfficeName | 
    export-csv -path $file.FullName -Append
```

Note that for symmetry I have specified `-Append` for both `Get-ADUser` calls and use `New-Item` to clear output from any previous run. This makes the code easier to maintain, as you don't need to take care which `Get-ADUser` call is the first one, when you add more queries or delete existing ones in the future.

---

Another approach is to wrap both `Get-ADUser` calls into a script block to effectively append their output streams. An advantage is that we can remove some duplicate code.

```
$OU1 = "OU=Standard users,OU=US,DC=x1,DC=contoso,DC=com','OU=Standard users,OU=AS, DC=x1,DC=contoso,DC=com"
$OU2 = "OU=Standard users,OU=US,DC=x1,DC=contoso,DC=com','OU=Standard users,OU=AS, DC=x1,DC=contoso,DC=com"

# Create a script block to append the output streams of both `Get-ADUser` calls.
& {
    Get-ADUser -Filter * -Searchbase $OU1 -Properties *
    Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase $OU2 -Properties *

} | Select-Object name, userPrincipalName, accountExpires, distinguishedName, physicalDeliveryOfficeName | 
    Export-Csv -Path "c:\users\$env:USERNAME\desktop\2-OU-List.csv"
```

The line `& {` uses the [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.2#call-operator-) to immediately execute the following script block.

The last line ends the script block and pipes its output, which consists of the serially combined output of both `Get-ADUser` calls, to `Select-Object` and then to `Export-Csv`. There is no need for `-Append` as we write the file in one go.

Comment: Maybe worth mentioning that using `-Properties *` is very inefficient when you only want two extra (besides the default) properties in the output